# how to display different function in a same textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code with javascript. My average value displays correctly but my find  minimum is not displaying anything. Its supposed to show when the user clicks on the find min button on the box.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculate Your Grade</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
<script>
    var $ = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    var calculateGrade = function () {
        var exam1 = parseFloat($("exam1").value);
        var exam2 = parseFloat($("exam2").value);
        var exam3=parseFloat($("exam3").value);

        if (isNaN(exam1) || isNaN(exam2) ) {
            alert("All three entries must be numeric");
        }
        else {
            var average = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3) / 3;
            $("average").value = average;
        }

        }   
        var min  = function () {
        var exam1 = parseFloat($("exam1").value);
        var exam2 = parseFloat($("exam2").value);
        var exam3=parseFloat($("exam3").value);

        if ( (exam1<exam2) && (exam1<exam3)){
            $("mini").value=exam1;}
        else if ((exam2<exam1) && (exam2<exam3)){
            $("mini").value=exam2;}
        else {
            $("mini").value=exam3;
            }       
    }
        window.onload = function () {
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateGrade;
        $("mini").onclick = min;

        $("exam1").focus();
        }









</script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Calculate Average</h1>
    <label for="exam1">Exam1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam1"><br>
    <label for="exam2">Exam2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam2"><br>
    <label for="exam3">Exam3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam3"><br>
     <label for="average"></label>
    <input type="text" id="average"disabled ><br>  
    <label>&nbsp;</label>



    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calc Avg">
    <input type="button" id="mini" value="Find min"> 
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems you are setting the min as the value of the mini button.

Comment: Thats the problem i am having but how do you set the value of minimum into the text box instead of button? please show me. really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `min` function. Instead of setting the value of textbox (probably, missing in your code example) you are setting the value of button "`mini`" (which is incorrect).

**Update:**
You need to be including one more textbox `<input type="text" id="txtMin" disabled ><br>`

and update your `min` function to set the value of it, as follows:

```
$("txtMin").value=exam1;
...
$("txtMin").value=exam2;
...
$("txtMin").value=exam3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculate Your Grade</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
<script>
    var $ = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    var average = function () {
        var exam1 = parseFloat($("exam1").value);
        var exam2 = parseFloat($("exam2").value);
        var exam3 = parseFloat($("exam3").value);

        if (isNaN(exam1) || isNaN(exam2) || isNaN(exam3)) {
            alert("All three entries must be numeric");
        }
        else {
            var average = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3) / 3;
            $("result").value = average;
        }
    }   

    var min  = function () {
        var exam1 = parseFloat($("exam1").value);
        var exam2 = parseFloat($("exam2").value);
        var exam3 = parseFloat($("exam3").value);

        if (isNaN(exam1) || isNaN(exam2) || isNaN(exam3)) {
            alert("All three entries must be numeric");
        } else {
            $("result").value = Math.min(exam1,exam2,exam3); 
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        $("average").onclick = average;
        $("mini").onclick = min;
        $("exam1").focus();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Calculate</h1>
    <label for="exam1">Exam1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam1"><br>
    <label for="exam2">Exam2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam2"><br>
    <label for="exam3">Exam3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="exam3"><br>
     <label for="average"></label>
    <input type="text" id="result" disabled ><br>  
    <label>&nbsp;</label>

    <input type="button" id="average" value="Calc Avg">
    <input type="button" id="mini" value="Find min"> 
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much. using a math function seems easier than what i was trying to do.